# VBA For Each loop several ranges

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, foreach

VBA beginner here.

I have 3 dynamic named ranges I would like to run through, each has the same number of entries.
Currently, I'm looping through each one individually:

```
For Each M in worksheets(x).Range("Range1")
    For Each N in worksheets(x).Range("Range2")
        For Each O in worksheets(x).Range("Range3")
            IF ( Depends on M) Then
                (Does things to ranges N and O)
            End IF                
        Next
    Next
Next
```

But the values in each of these match up, so the majority of this is unnecessary - this loops through up to 80^3 times, whereas only 80 times are actually necessary as the data matches up between the ranges.

So I would like a single loop to go through all the Ms in Range1 (for example), and also go through the rows in Ranges 2 and 3 at the same rate:
So It will consider M(1),N(1),O(1), then go on to M(2),N(2),O(2), etc all the way down until it hits a empty cell in Range1 (the end - its dynamic), at which point it should stop.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: use a single loop and check the values with `if M(1) = N(1) and N(1)=O(1) and M(1) = O(1)` etc. or nested if `if ... then else if ... then ... else ... end if`

Comment: `If` _what_ `Depends on M`???

Comment: @PaulOgilvie If M(i) = "specific value" then:... else if non empty, do something else. (It doesn't matter for the purposes of the question)

Comment: @psychicebola sorry I should've been more clear, N and O are ranges in excel based on M, they are not equal. They are set in the loop dependent on the values M takes (and then other data inbetween - I have this all sorted). Basically what I want is if the loop looks at row i of range1, it only needs to look at row i of the other 2 ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will somehow have to link the information from M to the ranges for N and O. From your code it is not too clear how these are linked, but if the rows are the same, you can do the following:

```
For Each M in worksheets(x).Range("Range1")
    IF ( Depends on M) Then
        Do something to RangeN.Rows(M.row) 
        Do something to RangeO.Rows(M.row) 
    End IF                    
Next
```

Comment: This looks like it would do it. Thanks!